# Choppy Scrolling UICollectionView when displaying videos

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, video, uicollectionview

I have a collectionViewCell which can display either image or video. I download both images and videos from the internet and display them in the collection view. I also cache both images and videos. However, I noticed that when a video is in a cell, the scrolling becomes quite choppy. This problem doesn't really occur with images. I suspect this may be because I'm doing something that should be done on the background thread on my main thread. However, I checked that all the downloading is done on the background thread so I'm not sure what it could be. Below I attach my cellforitem method as well as the two functions I use for downloading and caching videos and images.

Here is my cellforitem method:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell =  collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! FeedCell

    cell.likesLabel.text = ""
    cell.commentLabel.text = ""
    cell.gradientOverlay.alpha = 0
    cell.mainVideoView.view.alpha = 0
    cell.backgroundImageView.alpha = 0
    cell.backgroundImageView.image = nil
    cell.commentIcon.alpha = 0
    cell.upvoteImageView.alpha = 0
    cell.downvoteImageView.alpha = 0
    cell.commentLabel.alpha = 0
    cell.likesLabel.alpha = 0

    cell.alpha = 0

    if (indexPath.row < self.myFeed!.count) {
        cell.likesLabel.text = self.myFeed![indexPath.row].likes_amount!
        cell.commentLabel.text = self.myFeed![indexPath.row].comments_amount!

        if (self.myFeed![indexPath.row].resource_type == "image") {

            cell.mainVideoView.player?.pause()
            let temp = NSURL(string: self.myFeed![indexPath.row].resource_URL!.absoluteString)

            if let cached_im = self.myFeed![indexPath.row].image {
                cell.backgroundImageView.image = cached_im
                print("CACHING IMAGE IN FUNCTION")
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    cell.alpha = 1
                    cell.backgroundImageView.alpha = 1
                    cell.mainVideoView.view.alpha = 0
                    cell.gradientOverlay.alpha = 1
                    cell.commentIcon.alpha = 1
                    cell.upvoteImageView.alpha = 1
                    cell.downvoteImageView.alpha = 1
                    cell.commentLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.likesLabel.alpha = 1
                }, completion: { (boolean) in

                })
            }
            else {
                cell.backgroundImageView.loadImageUsingCache(url: temp!, { (completed) in
                    if (completed) {
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                            cell.alpha = 1
                            self.myFeed?[indexPath.row].image = cell.backgroundImageView.image
                            cell.backgroundImageView.alpha = 1
                            cell.mainVideoView.view.alpha = 0
                            cell.gradientOverlay.alpha = 1
                            cell.commentIcon.alpha = 1
                            cell.upvoteImageView.alpha = 1
                            cell.downvoteImageView.alpha = 1
                            cell.commentLabel.alpha = 1
                            cell.likesLabel.alpha = 1
                        }, completion: { (boolean) in

                        })

                    }
                })
            }
        }
        else if (self.myFeed![indexPath.row].resource_type == "video") {

            if let cached_url = self.myFeed![indexPath.row].video_URL {
                cell.mainVideoView.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: cached_url as URL))
                cell.mainVideoView.player?.isMuted = true
                cell.mainVideoView.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                cell.mainVideoView.showsPlaybackControls = false
                cell.mainVideoView.player?.play()
                print("CACHING VIDEO IN FUNCTION")
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    cell.alpha = 1
                    cell.backgroundImageView.alpha = 0
                    cell.mainVideoView.view.alpha = 1
                    cell.gradientOverlay.alpha = 1
                    cell.commentIcon.alpha = 1
                    cell.upvoteImageView.alpha = 1
                    cell.downvoteImageView.alpha = 1
                    cell.commentLabel.alpha = 1
                    cell.likesLabel.alpha = 1


                }, completion: { (boolean) in
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(cell,
                                                           selector: #selector(cell.playerItemDidReachEnd),
                                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                           object: cell.mainVideoView.player?.currentItem)
                })
            }
            else {
                let url_to_pass = self.myFeed![indexPath.row].resource_URL!
                let temp = NSURL(string: url_to_pass.absoluteString)

                cell.loadVideoUsingCache(url: temp!, { (complete, cached_url) in
                    self.myFeed![indexPath.row].video_URL = cached_url
                })
            } 
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

and here are my two methods for downloading and caching videos and images:

VIDEO DOWNLOAD:

```
    func loadVideoUsingCache(url : NSURL, _ completionHandler: @escaping (_ complete: Bool, _ cached_url : URL) -> ()) -> () {


    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory : NSString = paths[0] as NSString
    let str = url.absoluteString?.substring(from: (url.absoluteString?.range(of: "o/")?.upperBound)!)
    let str2 = str?.substring(to: (str?.range(of: "?alt=")?.lowerBound)!)
    let appFile = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(str2!)

    if let cached_URL = video_cache.object(forKey: NSURL(string : url.absoluteString!)!)  {
        self.mainVideoView.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: cached_URL as URL))
        self.mainVideoView.player?.isMuted = true
        self.mainVideoView.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        self.mainVideoView.showsPlaybackControls = false
        self.mainVideoView.player?.play()
        print("CACHING VIDEO")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.alpha = 1
            self.backgroundImageView.alpha = 0
            self.mainVideoView.view.alpha = 1
            self.gradientOverlay.alpha = 1
            self.commentIcon.alpha = 1
            self.upvoteImageView.alpha = 1
            self.downvoteImageView.alpha = 1
            self.commentLabel.alpha = 1
            self.likesLabel.alpha = 1


        }, completion: { (boolean) in
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                                   selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd),
                                                   name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                   object: self.mainVideoView.player?.currentItem)
            completionHandler(true, cached_URL as URL)
        })
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error ?? "")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                try data!.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: appFile), options: .atomicWrite)
                video_cache.setObject( NSURL(fileURLWithPath: appFile) , forKey: NSURL(string : url.absoluteString!)!)
                self.mainVideoView.player?.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: appFile)))
                self.mainVideoView.player?.isMuted = true
                self.mainVideoView.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
                self.mainVideoView.showsPlaybackControls = false
                self.mainVideoView.player?.play()
                print("DOWNLOADING VIDEO")
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                    self.alpha = 1
                    self.gradientOverlay.alpha = 1
                    self.gradientOverlay.alpha = 1
                    self.commentIcon.alpha = 1
                    self.upvoteImageView.alpha = 1
                    self.downvoteImageView.alpha = 1
                    self.commentLabel.alpha = 1
                    self.likesLabel.alpha = 1
                    self.backgroundImageView.alpha = 0
                    self.mainVideoView.view.alpha = 1

                }, completion: { (boolean) in
                    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.playerItemDidReachEnd),
                                                           name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                           object: self.mainVideoView.player?.currentItem)
                    completionHandler(true, URL(fileURLWithPath: appFile))
                })
            }
            catch _ {
                print("error saving video")
                return
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}
```

IMAGE DOWNLOAD:

```
  extension UIImageView {


  func loadImageUsingCache(url : NSURL, _ completionHandler: @escaping (_ complete: Bool) -> ()) -> () {


    self.image = nil

    if let cachedImage = image_cache.object(forKey: url) {
        self.image = cachedImage
        completionHandler(true)
        print("CACHING IMAGE")
        return
    }

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error ?? "")
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let im = UIImage(data : data!) {
                image_cache.setObject(im, forKey: url)
                print("DOWNLOADING IMAGE")
                self.image = im
                completionHandler(true)
            }
        }
        }.resume()
}

}
```